# Google Tag Manager css selector to get value of third span

Tags: css

How do i get the value of 93 from the third span in this example?

```
<div class="rating-result">
<span>
<span>
<span itemprop="ratingValue">93</span>% of <span 
itemprop="bestRating">100</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Ive tried things like this but neither works:

div.rating-result > span > span
or 
div.rating-result > span:nth-child(3)

Comment: do you want to get the value or apply some styles?? if you want to get the value then you need to go with jquery or javascript.

Comment: I need the value of 93

Comment: jquery is fine for you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var el=document.querySelector('span[itemprop=ratingValue]').textContent;
```

Your result (93) is in el variable.
With tis line your get all span with an attribute itemprop which add value ratingValue.
Be carrefull document.querySelector('span[itemprop=ratingValue]') can return only the first occurence.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then you can use the following way to get the text 93.

```
$("div.rating-result span[itemprop='ratingValue']").text()
```

or

```
$("div.rating-result > span > span > span:first-child").text()
```

```js
console.log($("div.rating-result > span > span > span:first-child").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating-result">
<span>
<span>
<span itemprop="ratingValue">93</span>% of <span 
itemprop="bestRating">100</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Css selector of div.rating-result > span > span > span:first-child also worked.